# Is it normal for Tor to randomly connect to various hidden services?

Tags: whonix, nyx, qubes

I am using Qubes-Whonix. For a while now I have noticed, by monitoring ARM, that Tor attempts to connect to various random hidden services. Unplugging my connection results in rows of the following:

> "[notice] Tried for 126 seconds to get a connection to [onion URL]. Giving up."

During regular operations, I sometimes find this manner of messages:

> "[notice] Closing stream for [onion URL]: hidden service is unavailable (try again later).

I am not setup as a relay. Is this normal behavior?

It also does not help that today, while reading through the tor logs in a separate terminal window, ARM asked me to press 'c' in order to confirm if I want to purge the logs, all by itself. Visual glitches are not rare either.

Answer (score 1):

Not normal for Tor, but normal for Whonix.

It's sdwdate.

Details:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Dev/TimeSync